# i seen facebook #100 error when facebook post wall?

Tags: php, facebook, api

This is my code:

```
<?php

require 'src/facebook.php';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => '25856*****93875',
    'secret' => '7c3e95185d681ee6****8bcef1305352',
    'cookie' => true
));
$user = $facebook->getUser();

if($user) { 
    try {
       $statusUpdate = $facebook->api('/me/feed', 'post', array('link' => 'http://www.firsatdergisi.com/'));
     } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
          echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
else
{
    $url = 'https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=25856*****93875&redirect_uri=http://apps.facebook.com/gunlukburcpaylas/&scope=email,read_stream,publish_stream';
    echo "<a href='". $url ."'>login</a>";
}


?>
```

Error: (#100) The post's links must direct to the application's connect or canvas URL.

what i should?

Answer (score 1):

The error appears to tell you all you need to know - you can only post a link to your application's connect or canvas url, not directly to an OAuth dialog.